# iphone - <Project Name>.sqlite

Tags: iphone

I am playing with core data. I have managed to make it work but now a file named .sqlite appeared on my app's directory.

I suppose this is the database file the managed object uses but wasn't it supposed to have a proper name?

```
<Project Name>.sqlite
```

appears to be something that wasn't named at all.

So, is this the correct name? if not, where do I change this name or if this is not necessary, how do I get rid of this?

thanks.

Comment: You can find the Core Data setup methods in your AppDelegate... Maybe you can find a clue there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using the boilerplate code supplied by Apple there should be a method in your AppDelegate that sets up the persistent store. You can change the name of your database directly in there.